# XML linq query lists first elements but not all

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have this XML file that I parse into its elements and create a list of a custom object Module.

```
XDocument kobra = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(results.OuterXml));
XNamespace ns = "#RowsetSchema";

var kobraNodeList = from s in kobra.Descendants(ns + "row")
                    select new Module
                    {
                         id = s.Attribute("ows_ID").Value,
                         name = s.Attribute("ows_Title").Value,
                         sourceFile = s.Attribute("ows_Source_x0020_Message_x0020_File_").Value,
                         scope = Scope.KOBRA,
                         component = string.Empty
                    };
```

and here's my Module struct:

```
public struct Module
{
    public string name;
    public Scope scope;
    public string component;
    public int wordCound;
    public string id;
    public string sourceFile;
}
```

The code works fine, but things get weird when I try to convert the var kobraNodeList into a list of Modules, I get a `System.NullReferenceException` at the `AddRange` line:

```
this.moduleList = new List<Module>;
this.moduleList.AddRange(kobraNodeList);
```

When trying to debug, I notice that although `kobraNodeList.Count()` also returns `System.NullReferenceException`,  a `kobraNodeList.Any()` returns `true`, and `kobraNodeList.First()` returns a perfectly valid and correct Module struct with the desired data.

The XML file is valid, and if I replace the linq query with this:

```
var kobraNodeList = from s in kobra.Descendants(ns + "row")
                    select  s;
```

I get a valid list of XElement, which I can `Count()` ok.
Can someone explain me what's wrong? BTW, I'm using .NET 3.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like one (or more) of `kobra.Descendants` has `ows_ID`, `ows_Title` or `ows_Source_x0020_Message_x0020_File_` attribute missing.

Linq uses [deferred execution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943859.aspx), so it won't try to build the sequence until you ask for the items. When you call Any() or First(), it only needs the first item in the sequence to work, which tells me that the first item in `kobra.Descendants` does have all of the required nodes.

However, one of the items after the first is probably missing at least one of those attributes - so you end up asking for the `Value` of a `NULL` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Inside

```
select new Module 
{
    // properties...
}
```

You could be running into a NullReferenceException as you access `.Value` on elements that might not exist in the XML document. Your first object in the collection is likely fine, hence your results when using `Any()` or `First()`. Subsequent items could be missing elements/attributes you are trying to use.

Try this as a replacement instead of using `.Value` directly.

```
id = (string)s.Attribute("whatever") // etc.
```

Comment: Holy sh** you're right, I was 100% sure the XML file was complete with all attributes and couldn't be the cause. thx!

Answer (score 0):

One of your lines such as `s.Attribute("ows_Source_x0020_Message_x0020_File_")` will be returning null for one of the records so `s.Attribute("ows_Source_x0020_Message_x0020_File_").Value` would cause the null reference exception.